# How can one verify distributional assumptions for testing procedures, if only one draw from each distribution is available

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, model, assumptions

I am currently dealing with a situation in which the Wilcoxon signed rank test (WSRT) is a possible candidate to be applied to the data. So let`s say we have $n$ pairs of Random Variables $(X_i, Y_i)$ and the corresponding differences $Z_i=X_i-Y_i$ the assumptions of the WSRT are:

1. $Z_i$ are mutually independent, $i=1...n$
2. The differences $Z_i$ are each drawn from a continuous, symmetric distribution function $F_i$ with common median $\theta$

I wonder however, how on earth I am supposed to verify whether assumption $(2)$ is reasonable, as I only have one draw from each distribution? It seems to me that all I can do is to watch out for grave violations of these assumptions, but one does not have a real way to validate the assumptions.

This leads me to my actual qestion: How bad is ist if these assumptions are violated and I apply the test nonetheless?

Comment: The null hypothesis of the WSRT includes the assumption that [all the $F_i$ are *identical.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Assumptions_and_formal_statement_of_hypotheses)  You therefore have $n$ draws from this distribution, not one.

Comment: Hollander et al say otherwise, they explicitely mention that the distributions do not necessarily have to be the same.

Comment: Could you provide an exact quotation?

Comment: On page 40 of Nonparametric statistical methods by Hollander et al it says: "Each $Z_i, i= 1, . . . , n$ comes from a continuous population (not necessarily the
same one) that is symmetric about a common median $\theta$. If $F_i$ represents the
distribution function for $Z_i, i = 1, . . . n,$,this assumption requires that
$F_i (\theta + t ) + Fi (\theta− t ) = 1$, for every $t$ and $i = 1, . . . , n$."

Comment: Your link is not about the wilcoxon signed rank test

Comment: Thank you--I did link to the wrong article.  The WSR test is described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#Assumptions -- where the iid assumption is still explicitly made.

Comment: Ok so apparently these are just two different versions of the test. In Hollander`s version the symmetry of the differences is part of the assumptions, while in the wikipedia article the symmetry of the differences is the Null-Hypothesis.